# How to place a Column in a title of FlexibleSpaceBar in SliverAppbar

Tags: flutter, scroll, title, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar

I am working with SliverAppBar, where I used an image in flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar to fade it during scrolling. I also used a title of FlexibleSpaceBar, which is placed under the image, so when I am scrolling down, an image disappears and title stays up, what is perfect!

Problem happens once I try to put a Column in a title of FlexibleSpaceBar. In that case title is not placed under the image, but on top of the SliverAppBar. Is it possible to put somehow a Column in a title and make it movable during scrolling?

Comment: Can you include sample code that will reproduce the same error

Comment: Currently I am away from the code source. Are you able put a column in a title and make scrollable in any way?

Comment: I think you can use `SliverPersistentHeader` for more control/ also you can put column on  `FlexibleSpaceBar`